# MPD MPC error, timeout after stopping, clearing playlist, load and play again

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian, mpd

I'm getting crazy with MPD/MPC. I'm trying a basic use, playing a web playlist. My problem is when I try to stop it and then start playing again.

**LOADING:**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo mpd
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /var/lib/mpd/state
sw_volume: 100
audio_device_state:1:My ALSA Device
state: stop
random: 0
repeat: 0
single: 0
consume: 0
crossfade: 0
mixrampdb: 0.000000
mixrampdelay: -1.000000
playlist_begin
playlist_end
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mpc
volume:100%   repeat: off   random: off   single: off   consume: off
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mpc load http://www.wefunkradio.com/play/radio.pls
loading: http://www.wefunkradio.com/play/radio.pls
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mpc play
http://wefunkhub.com/radiodrops/introdrop-keithmurray2.mp3
[playing] #1/3   0:00/0:00 (0%)
volume:100%   repeat: off   random: off   single: off   consume: off
```

**STOPPING AND CLEARING:**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mpc stop
volume:100%   repeat: off   random: off   single: off   consume: off
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mpc clear
volume:100%   repeat: off   random: off   single: off   consume: off
```

I can see that this does not change immediately. It takes some time to clear (and it still shows "state:play"):

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /var/lib/mpd/state
sw_volume: 100
audio_device_state:1:My ALSA Device
state: play
current: 1
time: 103.685000
random: 0
repeat: 0
single: 0
consume: 0
crossfade: 0
mixrampdb: 0.000000
mixrampdelay: -1.000000
playlist_begin
song_begin: http://wefunkhub.com/radiodrops/introdrop-keithmurray2.mp3
mtime: 0
song_end
song_begin: http://s-05.wefunkradio.com:81/wefunk64.mp3
Title: WEFUNK Show 310 / next is Show 381
Name: ((( WEFUNK Radio ))) . raw uncut funk . classic & underground hip-hop
mtime: 0
song_end
song_begin: http://s-00.wefunkradio.com:81/wefunk64.mp3
mtime: 0
song_end
playlist_end
```

after some minutes I have state file clear, but I'm unable to play again:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /var/lib/mpd/state
sw_volume: 100
audio_device_state:1:My ALSA Device
state: stop
random: 0
repeat: 0
single: 0
consume: 0
crossfade: 0
mixrampdb: 0.000000
mixrampdelay: -1.000000
playlist_begin
playlist_end
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mpc load http://www.wefunkradio.com/play/radio.pls
loading: http://www.wefunkradio.com/play/radio.pls
error: Timeout
```

and everything starts failing:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mpc
error: Timeout
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mpc stop
error: Timeout
```

Only solution I found it to kill -9 mpd, and still sometime is working and some others not. 
I'm trying to find a rule to be able to reproduce the error but I cannot.

Any suggestion?
the scope is to:

- load the web playlist
- play it
- stop it
- clear the playlist
- load it again
- play it again

thanks in advance

**UPDATE**
waiting a lot of time between killing MPD, restart MPD, load playlist and play it, now it works. Is it time related?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo mpd --kill
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo killall mpd
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pgrep mpd
4631
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ netstat -pln | grep mpd
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo netstat -pln | grep mpd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6600          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4631/mpd        
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo kill -9 4631
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo netstat -pln | grep mpd
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mpc
error: Connection refused
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo mpd
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mpc
volume:100%   repeat: off   random: off   single: off   consume: off
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /var/lib/mpd/state
sw_volume: 100
audio_device_state:1:My ALSA Device
state: stop
random: 0
repeat: 0
single: 0
consume: 0
crossfade: 0
mixrampdb: 0.000000
mixrampdelay: -1.000000
playlist_begin
playlist_end
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mpc load http://www.wefunkradio.com/play/radio.pls
loading: http://www.wefunkradio.com/play/radio.pls
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mpc play
http://wefunkhub.com/radiodrops/introdrop-keithmurray2.mp3
[playing] #1/3   0:00/0:00 (0%)
volume:100%   repeat: off   random: off   single: off   consume: off
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Comment: any idea? still not having a solution to this :(